# Updating secondary list item based on primary list item change

Tags: sharepoint-online, updatelistitems

As the title should suggest, I'm trying to get SharePoint to automatically update *List B* item whenever a list item in *List A* is changed.

In this case, when an item is created in *List A* it also creates an item in *List B* with some of the same columns (List B also has other columns). This was done with a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 and works just fine.

Both *List A* and *List B* have a column called Notes. What I would like to happen is for the Notes field in *List B* to be updated when the corresponding Notes field in *List A* receives a value (user enters a note).

It seems like this should be the easiest workflow in the world to make, but I have tried a bunch of different ways to do this and I still can't my workflow to make the update to *List B*. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a workflow on the list A like the following:

[image]

Choose start workflow automatically when an item is modified:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "**Update List Item**" action to update value in second list(List B) and you need only one workflow in first list(List A). You need to run this workflow when item is changed or created.
You can also refer the image for reference.

[image]